# Using SSL with the python-instagram and localhost on sample-app.py

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, localhost, instagram

I plan on using the sample-app.py as a baseline of what I am building out and then expanding it from there.  Just want to get comfortable with the instagram API and build out from there.

I am trying to use the sample-app.py provided with python-instagram.  I have registered an application on instagrams website.  I set it up using the default redirect uri from sample-app.py:
        `http://localhost:8515/oauth_callback`        . 
I was able to authorize my instagram account to use the app, but when I click on any of the links, I get an error about the acccess-token.

When you look at the python command-line window that stays open, I get the following error:

"check_hostname needs a SSL context with either CERT_OPTIONAL or CERT_REQUIRED"

It appears that when the sample app is processing the lines below, it is trying to connect to instagram, but is not able to because SSL in local host is not set up properly.  How do I set up SSL so i do not get the above error?

access_token, user_info = unauthenticated_api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code)
        if not access_token:
            return 'Could not get access token'
        api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
        request.session['access_token'] = access_token
        print ("access token="+access_token)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps to solve this problem (it appears that it is actually several problems in aggregate causing this issue):

1. use openssl to create a ssl certificate and save cert to the same location as your python script.  Download open ssl here: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
2. You need to tweak bottle so that it will support ssl. Do so by adding the following lines in run in class `WSGIRefServer(ServerAdapter)`:

   `import ssl
   srv.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (
               srv.socket,
               certfile='server.pem',  # path to certificate
               server_side=True)`
3. There is a bug in python 3 and above(https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/issues/173).  I am using 3.4, so the bug could be fixed in 3.5.  In the instagram/oauth2.py file, change all `disable_ssl_certificate_validation=False` to `True`.